# GCC 4.8 fails while linking with libmagic

Tags: c++, c, gcc, libmagic

I am struggling with the issue while linking my code against libmagic:

```
test.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `magic_open'
test.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `magic_load'
test.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `magic_error'
test.c:(.text+0x84): undefined reference to `magic_close'
test.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `magic_file'
test.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `magic_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However the issue appears only when gcc version > 4.4. To compile, I am using the the following command:

```
gcc -L/usr/lib/ -lmagic  test.c -o test
```

An example code that uses libmagic might be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vivithemage/9489378). I have checked and this issue appears as well. Obviously the libmagic and libmagic-dev are installed on my system (Ubuntu 14.04).

Is there any way of handling this issue different thant downgrading gcc version?

Comment: I downvoted, because your question did not show enough research. You'll get zillions of answers by searching on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a FAQ, unrelated to your version of GCC.

<sup>I don't think that your compilation succeeded with `gcc-4.3`</sup>

Order of arguments to `gcc` matter a lot (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14623415/841108)); object files and libraries should go last (from the high-level to the low-level ones). Try with

```
 gcc  -Wall -g test.c -lmagic  -o mytest
```

BTW, don't call your executable `test` (but e.g. `mytest`) since `test` is often a shell builtin.